# Ubuntu Server - using Byobu: Ctrl+F2 does not split screen in vertical

Tags: byobu

Ubuntu Server (17.10 and 16.04)
using Byobu: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> does not split screen in vertical

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> splits screen in horizontal and all other key shortcuts work fine, just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> does not have any effect on Byobu screen

Comment: I can confirm this on QEMU. Seems to be a bug. But it works through SSH.

Comment: I can confirm same bug exists on Ubuntu Server 16.04

Comment: I just confirmed that Byobu works perfect on Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop. Frankly I think it would be much more useful on Server Edition since on Desktop Edition I can open any new Terminal window...

Comment: same on Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

Answer (score 4):

```
$ sudo nano /usr/share/byobu/keybindings/f-keys.tmux

# Change
bind-key -n C-F2 display-panes \; split-window -h -c "#{pane_current_path}"

# To
bind-key -n C-H display-panes \; split-window -h -c "#{pane_current_path}"

# Save the file

$ byobu-keybindings
Byobu keybindings: [OFF]
$ byobu-keybindings
Byobu keybindings: [ON]
```

Now, press `Ctrl-H` and it should split horizontally. Do this for any other keys that might be un-F'd.

Comment: Thank you, this put me on the right track. Adding my experience here too for future users. For some reason, `C-a |` which is the tmux shortcut for performing a vertical split is redefined in `/usr/share/byobu/keybindings/tmux-screen-keys.conf`, but `C-a %` is not. I added another entry similar to the `split -v` one (one line to unbind %, and another to perform a horizontal split, like the vertical one but with an added -h switch), and now the horizontal split via `C-a %` retains the current path. This was annoying me for a while. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Same behavior on Ubuntu Server 18.04, Ctrl + F6 does not kill the split in focus either.

From Dustin Kirkland, the author and maintainer of Byobu, [this seems to be a normal behavior for the TTY console](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260076/why-will-byobu-only-split-into-tabs-using-a-terminal-and-not-do-the-same-in-a-c) as he explained :

> "Sadly, the actual console TTY in Linux is not an actual Xterm, which is able to capture and support far more key presses.
>   I have long suspected that the Linux TTY could be taught to support the Shift-F-keys, though I've never gotten around to trying. Sorry."